# Aldol Reaction in Water Not Working

Tags: synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

I am conducting an Aldol formation reaction in water, and below is the experimental protocol I am following (from [*J. Org. Chem.* **1994,** *59*, 3590—3596](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00092a017?journalCode=joceah)):

> #### Formation of Aldol in Water using Yb(OTf)3 Catalyst
>
> To commercial **formaldehyde** solution ($\pu{1 mL}$) and THF ($\pu{3 mL}$) were successively added $\ce{Yb(OTf)3}$ ($\pu{0.04 mmol}$, $\pu{10 mol\%}$) and silyl enol ether **1-(Trimethylsiloxy)cyclohexene** ($\pu{0.4 mmol}$) in THF ($\pu{1 mL}$) at rt. The mixture was stirred for $\pu{24 h}$ at this temperature and then THF was removed under reduced pressure. Water was added and the product was extracted with dichloromethane. After the usual workup, the crude product was chromatographed on silica gel to give the pure adduct.

Despite multiple attempts, I was unable to get the aldol product. The procedure itself is not even that convoluted to follow. NMR shows bare starting materials. Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot my issue?

**Post edit:** *JOC* reference as follows:

S. Kobayashi, I. Hachiya, “Lanthanide Triflates as Water-Tolerant Lewis Acids. Activation of Commercial Formaldehyde Solution and Use in the Aldol Reaction of Silyl Enol Ethers with Aldehydes in Aqueous Media,” *J. Org. Chem.* **1994**, *59(13)*, 3590–3596 (DOI: 10.1021/jo00092a017).

Comment: Your JOC reference is a link to a paper on a different topic in Tetrahedron.

Comment: Also, we have no idea what the reference enolate is or what your enolate is. Depending on what the identities of these substances are, there's no reason for it to work a priori.

Comment: @Zhe: I put the info about *JOC* paper for your convenience.

Comment: @chemrese: You have described the procedure for hydroxymethylation of O-silyl enolates (ethers).  If you are using other aldehydes other than formaldehyde, there is an other procedure. Thus, it's better to described one of your failed attempts so that we have a clear picture.

Comment: @Zhe fixed it. The silyl enol ether I've used is: 1-(Trimethylsiloxy)cyclohexene

Comment: @chemrese I don't have journal access anymore. What substrates are given in the substrate table in the paper?

Comment: @Mathew Mahindaratne Apparently it worked under Nitrogen (done by my colleague) what's the point of running a reaction under N2 if water is used as a solvent?

Comment: @chemrese: Apparently, moisture is not the problem here. But, probably atmospheric $\ce{O2}$ is. Usually, we do reactions under $\ce{N2}$, mostly to prevent unnecessary oxidations by $\ce{O2}$, not moisture, unless your reactants are moisture sensitive such as organolithium.